# Пример из книги М.Лутца. Программирование на питон 4 изд. Наследование в классах

Tags: python

Добрый день. Я только учусь поэтому просьба сильно не пинать. Пасиб.
Вопрос в следующем.

Изучаю книгу М.Лутца Программирование на Питон 4е издание. Там реализован пример создания GUI состоящий из нескольких модулей:

- Пример 10.2. PP4E\Gui\Tools\guimixin.py (стр.770)
- Пример 10.3.    PP4E\Gui\Tools\guimaker.py(стр.775)
- Пример 10.5. PP4E\Gui\ShellGui\shellgui.py (стр 787)
- Пример 10.6. PP4E\Gui\ShellGui\mytools.py (стр. 789)
- Пример 10.7. PP4E\Gui\ShellGui\packer.py (стр. 791)
- Пример 10.8. PP4E\Gui\ShellGui\unpacker.py (стр. 791)
- Пример 10.9. PP4E\Gui\ShellGui\formrows.py (стр. 794)
- Пример 10.10. PP4E\Gui\ShellGui\packdlg.py (стр. 794)
- Пример 10.11. PP4E\Gui\ShellGui\unpkdlg.py (стр. 796)

Вот та часть которая вызвала затруднения. 
Атрибут setToolBar класса ShellGui ссылается на атрибут fetchCommands класса DictMenuGui, причем DictMenuGui не является супер классом класса ShellGui(как я думаю), но код работает. Подскажите пожалуйста почему setToolBar видит fetchCommands. Ниже приведена часть этого кода. Вся программа в приложении.
Спасибо огромное за помощь.

Shellgui.py

```
from tkinter import *
from guimixin import GuiMixin
from guimaker import *
class ShellGui(GuiMixin, GuiMakerWindowMenu): 
    def start(self): 
        self.setMenuBar() 
        self.setToolBar()
        self.master.title("Shell Tools Listbox")
        self.master.iconname("Sell Tools")
    def handleList(self, event):
        label = self.listbox.get(ACTIVE)
        self.runCommand(label)
    def makeWidgets(self):
        sbar = Scrollbar(self)
        list = Listbox(self, bg='white')
        sbar.config(command=list.yview)
        list.config(yscrollcommand=sbar.set)
        sbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        list.pack(side=LEFT, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
        for (label, action) in self.fetchCommands():
            list.insert(END, label)
        list.bind('<Double-1>', self.handleList)
        self.listbox = list
    def forToolBar(self, label):
        return True
    def setToolBar(self):
        self.toolBar = []
        for (label, action) in self.fetchCommands():            # Здесь ссылка на атрибут fetchCommands 
            if self.forToolBar(label):                                    # который находится в другом классе 
                self.toolBar.append((label, action, dict(side=LEFT))) 
        self.toolBar.append(('Quit', self.quit, dict(side=RIGHT)))
    def setMenuBar(self): 
        toolEntries = [] 
        self.menuBar = [ 
            ('File', 0, [('Quit', -1, self.quit)]),
            ('Tools', 0, toolEntries) 
            ]
        for (label, action) in self.fetchCommands():         # И здесь тоже
            toolEntries.append((label, -1, action))
class DictMenuGui(ShellGui):
    def fetchCommands(self):
        return self.myMenu.items()
    def runCommand(self, cmd):
        self.myMenu[cmd]()
class ListMenuGui(ShellGui):
    def fetchCommands(self):
        return self.myMenu
    def runCommand(self, cmd):
        for (label, action) in self.myMenu:
            if label == cmd: action()
```

Answer (score 1):

Если `fetchCommands()` не определён ни в самом классе ни его предках, то возможно `ShellGui` это абстрактный класс: если создаются только `DictMenuGui` и `ListMenuGui` объекты, то `fetchCommands()` всегда доступен.

Книгу и примеры не читал, отталкиваюсь только от кода, представленного в самом вопросе, поэтому не знаю согласуется ли эта интерпретация с намерением автора.

Answer (score 1):

Ответа я не нашел, но есть предположение. Поправьте если я ошибаюсь. Класс DictMenuGui имеет подкласс TextPak2 который находится в другом модуле и самый нижний класс в иерархии. В TextPack есть такая инструкция. DictMenuGui.**init**(self). Как я понял эта инструкция создает экземпляр наследующий весь список атрибутов вышестоящих классов. Т.о. при вызове sef.fetchCommands() из ShellGui.setToolBar интерпретатор ищет сначала в атрибутах экземпляра и только потом в атрибутах класса и надклассов. В общем как то так.

Answer (score 0):

def fetchCommands(self): теперь является атрибутом ShellGui и может   получать значения функций этих классов GuiMixin, GuiMakerWindowMenu а также переопределять их ну или вообще удалить метод из абстрактного класса